# jQueryUI Tab - Selected TabText on demand

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I need a function which will get the text of the currently selected tab. I can get the selected tab using events, but I need to get the text even if the selected event is not yet thrown.

Here's my event script,

```
    $( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
         _textOfTab=$(ui.tab).text();
     });
```

How can I just query the tabs for the currently selected one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<li>` of the selected tab will have a `ui-tabs-selected` class on it, you can use that to find the active tab.

```
$("#tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected").text()
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JArLv/).

Comment: Excellent. Works. I shudder to think how much work it took you to get a reputation of 121k....wow......that's some serious karma.